# Euler form of a non-metric connection

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes

Given an oriented real smooth vector bundle, the Euler class assigns a differential form on the base to each metric and metric-compatible connection on the bundle. Is there a reason that it is not possible to naturally extend this to define a differential form for each connection on the bundle? I am aware of why the Pfaffian process in particular fails, since the connection's curvature does not necessarily have the necessary skew-symmetry.

Comment: Look at Milnor's paper "On Fundamental Groups of Complete Affinely Flat Manifolds," Adv. Math. 25 (1977), 178-187.

Comment: Which part do you mean? I can't find any mention of differential forms there

Comment: I haven't looked in decades. But doesn't he give a bundle with flat affine connection whose Euler class is nonzero?

Comment: P.S. Take a look at this [nice paper of Bill Goldman's](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1108.0216.pdf).

Comment: Would it be wrong to say that such a bundle only rules out the possibility that such a "Euler form" is a polynomial of the curvature? In principle couldn't there be other possibilities?

Comment: First comment is that one needs oriented bundles for the Euler class. Second comment: The Euler class is still natural, in that you get it by pulling back the appropriate cohomology class on the Grassmannian. I'm not sure what you're looking for; if you have a connection with zero curvature and yet the Euler class is nonzero, what are you going to concoct from the curvature that will produce that nonzero class? ... Of course, there are secondary characteristic classes (Chern-Simons) in certain cases, built out of a transgression. But that won't produce Euler.